# Intergating dokuwiki and jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, dokuwiki

Dokuwiki us prototype, my site use Jquery.

If there is another way to alter Dokuwiki javascript, instead using jQuery.noConflict(), or/and var $j = jQuery on my jQuery?

I open all .js files on Dokuwiki, search for "$(" and replace it with "$DW(", and it works like a charms, but I had to deal with every Dokuwiki plugins that has javascript in it.

So, how to alter "$" in prototype libaries/ Dokuwiki?

Answer (score 1):

You are doing it the wrong way around. Just include jQuery after prototype then immediately make a call to `jQuery.noConflict()`. And in your code always write

`jQuery(..)` / `jQuery.[functionname](...)` instead of the usual `$` notation.

This way you can leave the whole existing javascript source of dokuwiki and all existing plugins untouched. And you can use jQuery in your code.

Or if you still want a short handle instead of writing jQuery you could create an alias for jQuery

```
<script ... include prototype ..</script>
<script ... include jquery ..</script>
<script ...>
    var jQ = jQuery.noConflict();
    //do something with prototype
    $("findme");
    jQ("div hideme").hide();
</script>
```

For more info check [jQuery.noConflict()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/)

Comment: I had tons of functions on my JQuery and its a production site, I don't want to alter them. Are you suggesting editing all of them or 
I can do it like this?

jQuery( 

$(function(){
... my jquery...
})

$(document).ready(function(){
... my doc.ready jquery...

})

);

Answer (score 0):

The way I did that was to create a very simple "plugin" that does nothing else than include an extra JS file in each page's header section.

All you need to do is to add a new directory under `lib/plugins` which contains a "plugin.info.txt" (see the other plugins for examples) and one file called "action.php" (plus any files you want to load, in this case a .js file).

That "action.js" file should just contain a class that extends "`DokuWiki_Action_Plugin`" with two functions:

Firstly, "register" to, well, register an event handler for when metadata is output:

```
public function register(Doku_Event_Handler $controller) {
    $controller->register_hook('TPL_METAHEADER_OUTPUT', 'BEFORE', $this,
            'handle_tpl_metaheader_output');
}
```

Secondly, the actual event handler, which is simply:

```
public function handle_tpl_metaheader_output(Doku_Event $event, $param) {
    global $ID, $conf, $INFO;
    if (page_exists($ID)) {
        $event->data["script"][] = array (
            "type" => "text/javascript",
            "src" => DOKU_BASE."lib/plugins/[YOURPLUGINNAME]/[YOURJSFILENAME].js"
        );
    }
}
```

And that's it. Then do as you please in the JS file.

Edit: of course, you still need to refer to jQuery by using "`jQuery()`" instead of "`$()`".